# How can I extract only the indexes of the array_diff function?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I extract only the indexes of the array_diff function?

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red", "pink");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Instead of it showing: Array ( [1] => blue   [3] => pink )
I want it to display only the indexes like this: 1, 3  (maybe inside a new array called $indexesresult)
(Reason being that I am comparing an online (mysqli) array with a localhost (mysqli) array and I have to remove whitepaces before I can compare the arrays- I tried hundreds of ways around this but to no avail: array_diff does not like any type of whitespaces). With the indexesresult I can then get the original values back into the arrays to display the differences in a neat tabular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array_keys` would help.

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red", "pink");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
$indexesresult=array_keys($result); //<----- Here
print_r($indexesresult);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)
```

Comment: Part2 for display: foreach($indexesresult as $item) {
echo $item."<br>";
}
echo "<br><br>";

foreach($indexesresult as $key => $item) {
echo "Key ".$key.': '.$array1[$item]." from index: $item <br>";
}

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
print_r( array_keys($result) );
```